# Downgrading python within a conda enviorment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Hello I am trying to downgrade my python version within a conda environment. I was originally running 3.6 but I package I wanted required version 3.7. So I ran `conda install python=3.7` adn built then installed apex, the package I needed. however I now needed to return to python 3.6 so that I could install numpy 1.13.3. I ran `conda install --no-depspython=3.6` This gives me the a whole lot of package conflict errors .I then tried uninstalling python (to later reinstall) but this produces this error `RemoveError: This operation will remove conda without replacing it with another version of conda.`. So is there any possible way to downgrade my python version?

Comment: I've had this problem before, but I couldn't resolve this error despite multiple attempts. So, I created a new environment and activated the version.

Comment: @user2824374 I would do this but I need the apex package.

Comment: Downgrading in place is a waste of your time. Nearly every package has to be reinstalled. Instead, create a new environment.